# only one data is fetched from sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT 
TC_TXN.BOOKING_REF_ID,
TC_TXN.CREATION_TIME,
IFNULL(MAN_REQ.SUB_COMPANY_CODE,"") AS "SUB_COMPANY_CODE",
IFNULL(CONCAT(' / ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUB_COMP.BV_GROUP_FQN_NAME,'/',-1)),"") AS SUB_COMPANY_NAME,
"Company" AS "BILL_TO",
"" AS "REF",
BV_ENUM.VALUE,
MI_TXN.PRODUCT_CHARGES,
IFNULL(TC_TXN.VENDOR_PAYABLE_AMOUNT,0) AS VENDOR_AMOUNT,
IFNULL(MAN_REQ.TICKET_NO,(select TICKET_NO from TC_FLIGHTS_BOOK tfb join TC_TRANSACTION tcx on(tcx.TRANSACTION_ID=tfb.TRANSACTION_ID) join TC_FB_FARE_DETAILS tf on (tf.OID=tfb.OID) limit  1))  AS "TICKET_NO",
IFNULL(TC_FB.SP_PNR_NO,IFNULL(MAN_REQ.PNR_NO,"")) AS "PNR_NO",
MAN_REQ.TOUR_CODE,
TC_TXN.TRANSACTION_ID,
TC_TXN.REQUEST_ID,
MAN_REQ.EMPLOYE_ID,
"" AS "TCID" 







FROm TC_TRANSACTION TC_TXN 
    LEFT JOIN MANUAL_INVOICE_TRANSACTION MI_TXN ON (TC_TXN.TRANSACTION_ID = MI_TXN.TRANSACTION_ID)
    LEFT JOIN MANUAL_INVOICE_REQUEST MAN_REQ ON (MAN_REQ.REQUEST_ID = MI_TXN.REQUEST_ID) 
      LEFT JOIN TCP_ORGANIZATION SUB_COMP ON (SUB_COMP.ORGANIZATION_ID = TC_TXN.CUSTOMER_CODE)
       LEFT JOIN BV_ENUM_VALUES BV_ENUM ON (TC_TXN.BOOKING_TYPE = BV_ENUM.INT_CODE AND BV_ENUM.TYPE_NAME = 'BOOKING_TYPE')
       LEFT JOIN TC_FB_FLIGHT_DETAILS TC_FB ON (TC_FB.OID=TC_TXN.OID) 

       WHERE 
     TC_TXN.CREATION_TIME>=? and   TC_TXN.CREATION_TIME<= ? AND TC_TXN.CURRENT_BOOKING_STATUS=0
GROUP BY  TC_TXN.TRANSACTION_ID
```

when I am running this query for ticket_no column only 1st data is fetched. Remaining columns are fetching properly. i am using trying to solve this error for more than 2 days. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The subquery for the ticket_no field is not a corralated one, meaning it is going to return the same value for all records. But I do not really understand the question, so I cannot decide if this is the cause of the error or not. Pls describe in a more detsiled manner what you mean by "only 1st data is fetched"

Comment: for every row the ticket_no value is same.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

In the light of the comment by the OP ("for every row the ticket_no value is same"), the issue is that the subquery for the `ticket_no` field is not a correlated one. This means that its value does not depend on any value from the outer query:

```
...
IFNULL(MAN_REQ.TICKET_NO,(select TICKET_NO from TC_FLIGHTS_BOOK tfb join TC_TRANSACTION tcx on(tcx.TRANSACTION_ID=tfb.TRANSACTION_ID) join TC_FB_FARE_DETAILS tf on (tf.OID=tfb.OID) limit  1))  AS "TICKET_NO",
...
```

This also means that `MAN_REQ.TICKET_NO` field is always null, which begs the question why it is there in the first place.

Since the issue is with the data and the question does not describe how the tables are related, nor provides any sample data, I cannot provide an exact solution, only point out the root cause.